# Run ICE Validation against windows installer database using c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows-installer

I'm wondering if anyone can help.

I have an c# application to make modifications to multiple in house msi files.

We want to run ICE validation and get the results back in my application. I know i can run MsiVal2.exe as a process and output the results back to the app but i would ideally like to run it all via code.

There is an evalcom2.dll which appears to be written in c++ but there seems to be very little information around using this.
Im surprised that nobody seems to have done this or is there an easier way like using one of the wix libraries or some thing?

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Somebody has done that years ago in an open source project, https://sourceforge.net/p/sumsie/code/HEAD/tree/Src/ValidationModule/EvalCom.cs Analyze the code base and do the same.

Comment: It depends what you need to do specifically with the validation output, but this may help: https://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/blog/2013/11/05/valmakr-custom-windows-installer-validation/

Answer (score 0):

***WiX Toolkit***: I don't really use it manually that much (I validate using Orca), but the WiX toolset itself contains the binary [**`smoke.exe`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/alltools.html). I believe it is run for every build in Visual Studio? Not sure. The full [source available on github.com](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/tools/smoke).

Looks possible to adapt to your own project. You could also just pass it to the compiled [**`smoke.exe`**](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/alltools.html) I guess. In the code, you can see:

- Line 180: `validator.Validate(Path.GetFullPath(inputFile));`
- [Validator.cs](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/blob/develop/src/tools/wix/Validator.cs) is in the WiX project (https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix3/tree/develop/src/tools/wix)